# MessageLoggingElement.MaxMessagesToLog Property

Tags: wcf, trace

My WCF service trace file `wcf-trace-error.svclog` has exceeded size of 325MB+
I want to minimize its size from growing, what I tried is adding this to web.config file of my service

```
<diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging 
           logEntireMessage="true" 
           logMalformedMessages="true"
           logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
           logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
           maxMessagesToLog="800" 
       />
</diagnostics>
```

With the intention that `maxMessagesToLog` will solve my problem. But I am not completely sure that it will because there is not much description given on msdn for this property

> Gets or sets a value that specifies the maximum number of messages to
>   log.

Is this way correct?

And what actually the property does? Does it stop logging once it reaches to the specified number of messages logged?

Comment: As you have `logMalformedMessages` set to true, your log will continue to grow - from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731308%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  "Malformed messages do not count toward the maxMessagesToLog" - I just cleared a 56GB log file from production where maxMessagesToLog was zero!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct but not fully.

`maxMessagesToLog` indicates how many messages your log will store, but it says nothing about their size. Messages could be up to 256k (by default)

Use `maxMessagesToLog` with `maxSizeOfMessageToLog` (indicates maximum size of 1 message), so by multiplying `maxMessagesToLog` with `maxSizeOfMessageToLog` you can make a sugestion about your log maximum size.